# OrCAD Allegro PCB Designer Ground Plane

Tags: pcb, design, ground, ground-plane, orcad

i want to assign a black color to Ground Plane (GND 0), it's shape is polygon and it's color is gray like shown on below image, i have two questions:

is this a possible polygon shape to implement ?

i don't know if the other non GND tracks are too close to Ground Plane like i draw on below image, between this PCB circuit is for real implementation/assembly on a real presensitized board.

How do i change the color of the Gray Polygon Area of the Ground Plane, from Gray to black ?

i can only change the color of the tracks.

i followed this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nkzfqQw_wRg 
and did the same for my Ground Plane.
[image]
on Display Menu -> Color/Visibility (Color Dialog Window), none of the active colors are Gray, they only black and white (like i want), but the Ground Plane is Gray, but i want this Ground Plane Area with a black color.
[image]

sorry my english is not good.

Comment: Mouse over an edge of the polygon, right click and select "Show Element". Make sure what it says matches what you think it is; IE Etch on the Bottom Layer.

Comment: i figure it out, on Menu Display -> Color/Visibility -> Display -> Shapes Transparency to 100%. it was by default 40%, so thats explains the gray color. i still have one question: is this a possible polygon shape to implement ? or i just ground plane all the area, but the problem the ground plane is too close to the tracks sometimes, i need a distance of about 1mm, but i don't know how to that.

Comment: You should check with your board house to be sure, but it look OK to me. However, I assume you are doing this because you are expecting a lot of current in that track, if so, why not just change the width of it?